# Requesting access to SEND_SMS and GPS in Android SDK 23

Tags: android, permissions

I'm relatively new to Android programming.  So far, I'm working on a messaging app that will send a message via SMS and have the option to append GPS coordinates to the message.  The problem I have here is with SDK version 23, the permissions need to be requested at runtime, and I have not found a good example where I can request the needed permissions before running the app.  The code sample I have is below.

If I comment out this code section, Android Studio compiles the code, but I get an application crash when I tap the button that sends the message.  I do have the appropriate code in my AndroidManifest.xml for using SMS and GPS permissions.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity,
Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity,
        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS))
    {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Foo Messenger requires permission to send SMS",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else
    {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);

    }
}

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity,
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
    {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Foo Messenger requires permission to access GPS to be able to send your coordinates",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else
    {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);

      }
}
```

Comment: "I get an application crash when I tap the button that sends the message" -- [use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this). You might also consider posting the code that is run when you tap the button, as I do not see an `OnClickListener` in what you have posted at the moment.

Comment: My OnClickListener() only checks to see if the recipient ID and message fields both contain something, then calls another function to actually perform the send.  I've read where any permission requests not granted by the user to apps that need access to features considered 'dangerous' can cause apps to crash, so this is why I only posted the snippet for granting the permissions.

Comment: This is the problem as identified in the LogCat '10-02 10:53:52.783    3726-3726/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: MyProcess, PID: 3726
    java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10060 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.'

Comment: OK. Did you execute the code shown in your question? Did you accept the permission via the dialog that appeared when you made your `requestPermissions()` call? If you go into Settings > Apps > (your app) > Permissions, do you have the SMS permission? Is your `<uses-permission>` element in the right place?

Comment: I know the issue is with this snippet since I went into the settings for the app and manually granted the SMS and location permissions and the button does function as expected.

Comment: OK. Did you execute the code shown in your question? Did you accept the permission via the dialog that appeared when you made your `requestPermissions()` call?

Comment: I can't execute the code since it does not compile within Android Studio.  These are the errors I see:  "can't resolve symbol checkSelfPermission", Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS and PackageManager.PermissionGranted are being recognized as unknown classes, and MainActivity being passed to Activity.Compat.requestPermissions() is not being seen as an expression.  If I can get the permissions debugged here for SMS, it will also debug the other section with the GPS permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> can't resolve symbol checkSelfPermission

You need to update to a v23 edition of the `support-v4` artifact, in your `dependencies` in `app/build.gradle` (assuming that your app is in `app/`):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

> Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS and PackageManager.PermissionGranted are being recognized as unknown classes

You need to add `import` statements for `android.Manifest.permission` and `android.content.pm.PackageManager`.

> MainActivity being passed to Activity.Compat.requestPermissions() is not being seen as an expression

`MainActivity` is a class. Presumably, you want that parameter to be `this`, or maybe `MainActivity.this`.